# Boost phoenix or lambda library problem: removing elements from a std::vector

Tags: c++, boost-lambda, boost-phoenix

I recently ran into a problem that I thought boost::lambda or boost::phoenix could help be solve, but I was not able to get the syntax right and so I did it another way. What I wanted to do was remove all the elements in "strings" that were less than a certain length and not in another container.

This is my first try:

```
std::vector<std::string> strings = getstrings();
std::set<std::string> others = getothers();
strings.erase(std::remove_if(strings.begin(), strings.end(), (_1.length() < 24 &&  others.find(_1) == others.end())), strings.end());
```

How I ended up doing it was this:

```
struct Discard
{
    bool operator()(std::set<std::string> &cont, const std::string &s)
    {
        return cont.find(s) == cont.end() && s.length() < 24;
    }
};

lines.erase(std::remove_if( lines.begin(), lines.end(), boost::bind<bool>(Discard(), old_samples, _1)), lines.end());
```

Comment: In your "ended up doing" code snippet, there's no need for Boost Bind.  Just pass the set (reference) to the Discard constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need boost::labmda::bind to lambda-ify function calls, for example the length < 24 part becomes:

```
bind(&string::length, _1) < 24
```

EDIT

See "Head Geek"'s post for why set::find is tricky.  He got it to resolve the correct set::find overload (so I copied that part), but he missed an essential boost::ref() -- which is why the comparison with end() always failed (the container was copied).

```
int main()
{
  vector<string> strings = getstrings();
  set<string> others = getothers();
  set<string>::const_iterator (set<string>::*findFn)(const std::string&) const = &set<string>::find;
  strings.erase(
    remove_if(strings.begin(), strings.end(),
        bind(&string::length, _1) < 24 &&
        bind(findFn, boost::ref(others), _1) == others.end()
      ), strings.end());
  copy(strings.begin(), strings.end(), ostream_iterator<string>(cout, ", "));
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: D'oh! Of course... thanks for the hint, I'll add that to mine too.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem, other than the `bind` calls (Adam Mitz was correct on that part), is that `std::set<std::string>::find` is an overloaded function, so you can't specify it directly in the `bind` call. You need to tell the compiler *which* `find` to use, like so:

```
using namespace boost::lambda;
typedef std::vector<std::string> T1;
typedef std::set<std::string> T2;

T1 strings = getstrings();
T2 others = getothers();

T2::const_iterator (T2::*findFn)(const std::string&) const=&T2::find;
T2::const_iterator othersEnd=others.end();

strings.erase(std::remove_if(strings.begin(), strings.end(),
    (bind(&std::string::length, _1) < 24
        && bind(findFn, boost::ref(others), _1) == othersEnd)),
    strings.end());
```

This compiles, but it doesn't work properly, for reasons I haven't yet figured out... the `find` function is never returning `others.end()`, so it's never deleting anything. Still working on that part.

EDIT: Correction, the `find` function *is* returning `others.end()`, but the comparison isn't recognizing it. I don't know why.

LATER EDIT: Thanks to Adam's comment, I see what was going wrong, and have corrected the problem. It now works as intended.

(Look at the edit history if you want to see my full test program.)